# What is the race of Iranians?

Tags: ancient-history

What is the race of Iranians? Most Iranians claim to be Aryans, is there any scientific evidence to support this?

Comment: Please add some source to show that Iranians claim to be Aryans.

Comment: I'm not sure that "race" is a concept that is either (a) scientifically defined or (b) subject to historical analysis.  This is not a history question. It may be within sociology, or genetics, or some other field, but I don't believe that this is a history question.

Comment: I was checking the popular claim that Indians are of two races: Aryan and Dravidian. Turns out Indians are mostly Caucasoid with two distinct populations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caucasian_race

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iranians "claim" to be Aryans because that was the shared ethnic *self-identification* ([Old Persian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Persian) `ariya`, [Sanskrit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit) `ārya`, [Zend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend) `airya`) of the Proto-Indo-Iranian peoples, originally the term for their tribal aristocracy. The modern [Iranian peoples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_peoples) are **some of** their descendents.

However, that is quite different form the "Aryans" that are normally associated with the word. That is a fictitious race invented by white supremacists featuring, in your own words from the other question, "blonde with blue eyes". As such there is no scientific evidence to support the idea that Iranians are the mythical master race of Nazi imagination.

The Iranic peoples are not some sort of "pure" descendents of the Proto-Indo-Europeans either. By the time the Proto-Iranian tribes had migrated to Persia, there were already people there, such as the [Mannaeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannaeans) and the [Elamites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elam). Iranians are therefore a mix of different lineages just like everyone else.